# Freeform purge submissions: unknown command

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

We try to delete the submissions from Freeform with the following terminal command:
`./craft freeform/purge/submissions --age-in-days=30`

And we get this error:

```
Craft can’t connect to the database. Check your connection settings.    

Unknown command: freeform/purge/submissions
Caused by: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "freeform/purge/submissions".'
```

---

Plugin-Info:
Freeform Plugin Version: 4.0.8 (lite, not pro)

Does anyone have a tip on how we can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we solved it:

It's a Freeform Pro feature, not available in Freeform Lite :)

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer? This isn't very helpful for someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that Craft CMS is unable to connect to the database and that the terminal command is not recognized.

You can resolve this issue by using this

1. Check your database connection settings in the Craft CMS control panel. Go to `"Settings"` -> `"Database"` and make sure the connection settings are correct.
2. Verify that your `Craft CMS` installation is running properly by accessing the `control panel` and checking for any `error` messages.
3. Make sure that the `Freeform` plugin is installed and enabled in Craft CMS. You can check this by going to `"Settings"` -> `"Plugins" in the control panel.
4. Check the `Freeform` plugin documentation to ensure that the command you are trying to use is valid for the version of `Freeform` you have installed. It's possible that the command has changed or is not available in the `Lite version` of the `plugin`.